# How to make Order with Parallel Express Checkout in Paypal?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-express

How can we place "Order" for parallel transactions in Express Checkout?

I set

`PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION = Order` 
 `PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION= Order` in `SetExpressCheckout` and then in `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`. but it gives error "Internal Error" 
 `PAYMENTINFO_1_ERRORCODE] => 10001`
    `[PAYMENTINFO_1_SHORTMESSAGE] => Internal Error`
    `[PAYMENTINFO_1_LONGMESSAGE] => Internal Error`
    `[PAYMENTINFO_1_SEVERITYCODE] => Error`
    `[PAYMENTINFO_1_ACK] => Failure` 
All is fine until  `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` 
 **why this internal error is coming?** 
 Thanks in advance

Comment: How is this related to Magento? Or am I missing something?

Comment: if i use
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION = Order 
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION= Order  in SetExpressCheckout and  then PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION = Sale 
PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION= Sale in   DoExpressCheckoutPayment. It all works fine and money gets transferred to vendor account. But I need to place "Order". Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [making Order in Paypal Parallel Express Checkout](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8543/making-order-in-paypal-parallel-express-checkout)

Comment: sorry but i am implementing it in magento 1.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION = Order PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION= Order
```

in

```
SetExpressCheckout and then PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION = Order PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION= Order
```

in `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`, "**Internal Error**" came in `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` response

Because **I used personal account id** in `PAYMENTINFO_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID` and `PAYMENTINFO_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID`.

So these parameters must have paypal Business account ids. (in my case the error was because of wrong usage of  paypal accounts where there must be Business accounts ).

Thanks

Comment: we can have PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION to PAYMENTREQUEST_n_PAYMENTACTION in parallel Express Checkout transactions.